# Is there any way to defend with magic in DFRPG?

Tags: magic, fate, dresden-files, defense

I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Evocation/Channeling can be used for a great deal of fun effects on your turn.

But what about when you need to make a defend roll against an enemy? As far as I can tell, the only way to defend yourself with magic is to create a block before the opponent attacks you.

The books are FULL of Harry tossing up a transient shield as a split-second reaction to someone shooting a gun, or an explosion, or whatever. In our short time with DFRPG so far, we have not figured out how this would be represented mechanically.

Comment: The other seems to be about defending _against_ magic reactively, this one seems to be about defending _with_ magic against apparently any number of things, including someone with a stick.

Comment: @doppelgreener I may be misunderstanding it, but I read it as about whether defending with magic (an evocation Shield rote) off-turn as a reaction to a physical, etc. attack is possible/permitted.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie You are correct! I searched before asking but that one didn't come up as the title is not the way I was asking it. But the first answer most definitely answers my question exactly as well.

Comment: While this is a duplicate, I do find it important to note that the previous question was asked and answered, there is a new book out which has changed the answer. The 'Paranet Papers' book has rules for reactive magic blocking.

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much @KveldUlf!! I would not have known were it not for this comment.